# Compiling Class files in Java has been confusing

Tags: java, compilation, javac

I have three `.java` files, `A.java`, `B.java` and `C.java`

`A.java`:

```
public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();

        a.display();
        b.display();
    }


    public void display() {

        System.out.println("In A");
    }
}
```

`B.java`:

```
public class B {

    public void display() {

        System.out.println("In B");

        C c = new C();
        c.display();
    }
}
```

`C.java`:

```
public class C {

    public void display() {

        System.out.println("In C");
    }
}
```

The program works fine. I compiled it as:

```
javac A.java
```

and this generated `A.class`, `B.class` and `C.class` files.

Then ran it as:

```
java A
```

It's output:

```
In A
In B
In C
```

Now the **PROBLEM** is here:
When I delete `A.class` and `C.class`, and **not** `B.java`, and recompiled `A.java`:

```
javac A.java
```

This generates only `A.class`. 
`B.class` was already present as not deleted.
But why was `C.class` not generated this time?

**NOTE**: `C.class` is generated when `B.class` is also deleted along with `A.class` and `C.class`. Or if I make any changes in `B.java` file pre-compilation.

Comment: your code for A & B, as is, does not compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compiled `A` it has a reference to `B` so it had to compile that as well.  `A` doesn't know about `C` so it doesn't compile that.

I suggest you use an IDE or a build tool such as `maven` as you will get much more complex project that this and this will become a nightmare trying to keep track of which files need to be recompiled when you change a file.

Answer (score 1):

Because C class is not used in the A class but in B class. Since you didn't deleted B class the compiler generates only the A class.
**A class has no dependency on C class then C class is not compiled.**